# Forecasts for intermittent demand using Croston's method

Tags: r, forecasting

I have a doubt with the arguments in the following croston formula.

The problem is the following, I am analyzing a period of 52 months of consumption and I want to predict the consumption in the next month.

The croston formula, `croston(y, h=10, alpha=0.1, x=y)`, what is the meaning of the h parameter in this context?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you are referring to the `forecast` package. In future, please state what package you are using.

If you bother to look at the help file, it is explained.

> `h`   Number of periods for forecasting.

In future, read the documentation before posting a question.